# How to achieve Glyph Level Kerning in Xelatex

Tags: xetex, symbols, indic

In the image below:

[image: Uni and Legacy]

The legacy font for Kannada is rendering correctly. Indic fonts have poor lookup table which makes rendering incorrect. So is there a possibility to automatically kern these by tapping into glyph tables using something like `\XeTeXglyph`.

Source Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={3cm,3cm},text={3cm,3cm},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\newcommand\eng[1]{\fontspec[Scale=.5]{Times New Roman} #1}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\eng{Legacy Font (Correct rendering)}\\
\fontspec[ExternalLocation]{brhknde}
vÉìöÊPÀvÉÃ, £ÉåöÊB

\eng{Kedage Unicode Font (Incorrect rendering)}\\
\fontspec{Kedage}
ತ್ಸೈಕತೇ, ನ್ಯೈಃ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you open to using LuaLaTeX? If so, and assuming the Kannada font you're using is an opentype font, you could create a so called "feature file" that provides improved kerning instructions for whatever glyph pairs you care about.

Comment: I would gladly. But Luatex has poor support for Indic texts.

Comment: Not sure if it's appropriate to blame LuaTeX and/or the `luaotfload` package for inadequate/insufficient kerning information contained in a font file. Anyway, my suggestion was to look into providing your own kerning information, contained in a feature file. that would augment and supersede what's stated in the font file itself.

Comment: LuaLatex is not supporting any Indic text of any language irrespective of any font.

Comment: @Mico LuaTeX does not use Harfbuzz and hopes to implement all complex text layout (glyph reordering, positioning etc.) by itself in Lua code, and as a consequence it implements barely any Indic scripts (it has some reasonable support for Devanagari now, but does not support Kannada script at all at this point). Even with a perfect font.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - Thanks for this additional piece of information.